# Check if user has used another provider firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have an app which has only used Google for signing in. To associate a user to the data in my database I made the mistake to use the Google account ID and not the firebaseuser id.

Now I am forced to use Apple sign in and if a user already has an account from signing in with Google, the data might be lost because I cannot associate the user to the data.

Any good ideas for handling this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to migrate the data over to the Firebase Authentication UID. If you then link the Apple account with the existing Google account, the UID will not change and thus the data will remain accessible when they sign in with either of those providers.

To migrate the data, you will need to have/create a mapping from the Google account IDs to the Firebase Authentication UIDs, which you can generate using the Admin SDK to get a list of all users. See [this example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#bulk_retrieve_user_data) in the documentation on how to only get users with the `google.com` provider.